# Chapter/Section/subsection etc. number doesn't increase in Octavo document class

Tags: counters, octavo

I'm using the `octavo` document class for writing a book with two parts and good number of chapters overall.

The problem is the chapter counter and subsequently section's, subsections' etc., are stuck at zero.

Even when I manually increase the chapter counter by `refstepcounter` or `stepcounter`, it doesn't increase when a new chapter is introduced. The same is true for sections and subsections. This translate into the numbering for equations, figure, theorems, etc. I checked and the document class is identical to that of a `book` class when it comes to counters (as far as I could see). I don't have this issue with standard `book` class, only with `octavo` class.

I think I can manually increase the counter every time I introduce new chapter or section, etc. But I would like to troubleshoot this and I haven't been able to figure this out yet. Could you please take a look at this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: The `octavo` class does not really have numbers. From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/octavo/tub-octavo.pdf): "Numbering is either simplified or has been done away with altogether. None of the headings bear numbers [...] Figures and tables are numbered consecutively through-out the book. The excellent capabilities of TEX to make and maintain cross-references leaves little in
favour of maintaining a chapternumber.figurenumber type of scheme. With some trepidation, this numbering system is also applied to equations.

Comment: There seems to be a substantial tradition of having a numbering system for equations which incorporates chapter and section numbers. As far as I can see, there is no particular need for such a system, once again bearing in mind the powerful cross-referencing capabilities of TEX, and it would also be inconsistent with the numbering system used for tables and figures."

Comment: So: if you want such numbers, then maybe this class is not the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
% octavoprob.tex  SE 542530
\documentclass{octavo}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} % number subsections change this to whatever depth you require
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

I don't know what this will do with the other numbering systems.